# Storing 3 different values in a single byte

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am working with a proprietary binary messaging protocol, where in one message a single byte is used to store 3 different values, like so:

```
Bit
7   IsArray (1 bit)
6   ArrayLength, MSB (4 bits, max size 2^4 = 16)
5
4
3
2   DataType, MSB (3 bits, max size = 2^3 = 8)
1
0
```

I want to extract these three values, and store them in three different properties in an object, `bool IsArray`, `byte ArrayLength` and `byte DataType`. I also need to go back from these three properties to a single byte

I seldom work at this level, and things got a bit messy when I went beyond setting or getting the single bit for IsArray, to trying to set several at once. I created three different masks that I thought would help me:

```
var IsArrayMask = 0x80;     // 1000 0000
var ArrayLengthMask = 0x78; // 0111 1000
var DataTypeMask = 0x07;    // 0000 0111
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve what I'm going for?

Edit: With some help from @stefankmitph, I discovered I had my shifting all messed up. This is how I go from 3 properties to a single byte now:

```
bool IsArray = true;
byte ArrayLength = 6;
byte DataType = 3;

byte serialized = 0x00; // Should end up as 1011 0011 / 0xB3

serialized |= (byte)((IsArray ? 1 : 0) << 7 & IsArrayMask);
serialized |= (byte)(ArrayLength << 3 & ArrayLengthMask);
serialized |= (byte)(DataType & DataTypeMask);
```

And back again, as per the answer below:

```
bool isArray = (serialized & IsArrayMask) == IsArrayMask; 
int arrayLength = (serialized & ArrayLengthMask) >> 3;  
int dataType = (serialized & DataTypeMask);
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the masks (i.e. post some code) and tell us how your approach is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int val = 0xBE;  //f.e. 1011 | 1110
var IsArrayMask = 0x80;     // 1000 0000
var ArrayLengthMask = 0x78; // 0111 1000
var DataTypeMask = 0x07;    // 0000 0111

bool isArray = ((val & IsArrayMask) >> 7) == 1;  // output: true

// as pointed out by @PeterSchneider & @knittl 
// you can get isArray in a probably more elegant way:
isArray = (val & IsArrayMask) == IsArrayMask;

// i keep both ways in my answer, because i think 
// the first one illustrates that you have to shift by 7 to get 1 (true) or 0 (false) 

int arrayLength = (val & ArrayLengthMask) >> 3;  // output: 7
int dataType = (val & DataTypeMask);             // output: 6
```

Comment: @PeterSchneider: you mean `bool isArray = (val & IsArrayMask) == IsArrayMask` (without the right shift)

Comment: *I had this wrong the first time, thanks @knittl. I deleted the wrong suggestion for clarity. --*
 
I think more canonical would be `bool isArray = (val & IsArrayMask) == IsArrayMask;`. The bit position is an implementation detail which can change. Unfortunately it's not possible to do that with length, although one could define the mask through (0xf << LEN_POS) with LEN_POS == 3, and shift the result back by LEN_POS bits

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it cleared a lot of things up. In my own solution to go from properties to the single byte, I use the ternary operator on the Boolean `IsArray`. Would you do this differently?

Comment: @Walkingsteak using ternary operator (here) is just matter of readability and/or coding style... so `(IsArray ? 1 : 0)` is fine.